# Difference between "//" and "/" in XPath?

Tags: xml, selenium, xpath

I was trying my hands on XPath for python-selenium.

I used [this link](http://www.jetairways.com/EN/SG/Home.aspx) for trying some XPaths' from tutorials:

So I tried these two variants of XPaths'.

1. This expression

   ```
   //webengagedata//preceding-sibling::*
   ```

returned 14 results

2. And this expression

   ```
   //webengagedata/preceding-sibling::*
   ```

returned 9 results

What does the "//" do to match 5 more results?

Comment: This is a great question, except for the off-site link.  (Questions should endeavor to present a *[mcve]* that will remain useful even if off-site resources change.)  See [**my answer below that**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43100904/290085) covers the concepts without dependence on any off-site resources.  Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### `/` vs `//` in general

Both `child` (`/`) and `descendant-or-self` (`//`) are **[axes in XPath](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#axes)**.

- `/` is short for `/child::node()/`.

  Use `/` to select a node's *immediate children*.
- `//` is short for `/descendant-or-self::node()/`.

  Use `//` to select
  a node, its children, its grandchildren, and so on
  recursively.

---

**`/` vs `//` with `preceding-sibling::*`**

Your specific question asks about the difference between `//preceding-sibling::*` and `/preceding-sibling::*`.

Since your data is offsite and complex, let's consider instead this present and simpler XML:

```
<r>
  <a/>
  <b>
    <c/>
    <d/>
  </b>
</r>
```

For this XML,

1. `/r/preceding-sibling::*` selects nothing because `r` has no
   preceding siblings.
2. `/r//preceding-sibling::*` selects the preceding siblings elements of
   all of the descendant or self *nodes* of `r`. That is, `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`.
   (Remember, `/r//preceding-sibling::*` is short for `/descendant-or-self::node()/preceding-sibling::*`, ***not*** `/descendant-or-self::*/preceding-sibling::*`)  Note that even though `b` and `d` are predecessor siblings to no *elements*, they are predecessor siblings to *text nodes* because the above XML has whitespace after `b` and `d`.  If all whitespace were removed, then only `a` and `c` would be selected.
3. `/r/descendant::*/preceding-sibling::*` selects the preceding sibling elements of all descendant *elements* of `r`.  That is, `a` and `c`.  Note that `b` and `d` are not selected because they are not preceding sibling elements to any descendant *elements* of `r` -- unlike the previous example, *text* nodes do not qualify.

Comment: I am able get an hold of 1 and 2. 
I am still confused with one small thing about descendants. 
Isn't descendant::* used to get all the child or sub-child nodes of the context node? If yes, shouldn't 

/r/descendant::*/preceding-sibling::*

return all the child nodes a and b and the sub-child nodes c and d?

Comment: @Prasanth, I have update the question to properly address your very insightful follow-up question, which made me realize a mistake in my explanation.  Thank you.

Comment: Oh, this is great. I was in an assumption that the output from `/descendant::*` will give `a` **'b'** `c` `d`, where `b` will not include its childs `c` and `d` as part of the output. But `b` element as a whole will be presented with its child `c` and `d` 
`<b> \n
    <c/> and hence the `preceding-element` -->  `c`.

Thank you so much **for your patience** and making me feel comfortable on answering my noob questions. This is my first question in stackoverflow, now I realize I am late to this beautiful world. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

For your example

```
//webengagedata/preceding-sibling::* ---> returned 9 results
```

Because there are only 9 tags which are exact sibling of `webengagedata`tags thats why it is showing 9 records

```
//webengagedata//preceding-sibling::* ---> returned 14 results
```

Here it is considering child tags as well as biziclop said `x/descendant-or-self::node()/y`

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that `x//y` is shorthand for `x/descendant-or-self::node()/y`.

That's all.

So while the first query selects all the descendants of `<webengagedata>` that have another tag after them, the second only selects the preceding siblings of the tag itself.

The rules of abbreviated xpath syntax are explained [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev).

Comment: Please tell me if this is right.. 
//webengage//preceding-sibling::* =  //webengage//child::* + //webengage/preceding-sibling::*

Answer (score -1):

difference between '/' and '//' in xpath is , '/' using for identify the elements in that region of area , '//' is for entire page after the condition

Comment: This answer uses such imprecise language that it's useless; it should be deleted.