# Getting error in loading xsl "invalid xpath expression"

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

Actually, we are getting invalid xpath expression on loading xsl file.
invalid xpath expression issue getting from below xsl script

```
    1. "<xsl:if test='z:row[index() $gt$ 5]'>"
    2. "<xsl:if test="//CICOUNT[@HASARCHIVE = 'Y' or @HASUNREVIEWED = 'Y']">"
    3. "<xsl:if test="//CICOUNT[@HASARCHIVE = 'Y' and @HASUNREVIEWED = 'N']">"
    4. "<xsl:template match="z:row[index() $lt$ 6]">"
```

Above issue we are getting because we modifying the old old Microsoft WD-xsl language which was introduced in IE4 in 1998.

Thanks in advance

Comment: In addition to @kjhughes post below, also note that the `//` in rules 2 and 3 mean that these will evaluate to `true` if **any** `CICOUNT` **anywhere in the file** has an attribute `HASARCHIVE` with a value of `Y`. This `//` notation appears to be a common cause of confusion.

Comment: See [**Difference between “//” and “/” in XPath**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43100052/difference-between-and-in-xpath) for a clear explanation the difference between `//` and `/`, but know that `//` would not cause an "invalid xpath expression" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with those XPath expressions, including

- `z` namespace prefix may not have been declared, depending upon
  context.
- `index()` is an unknown function; may want `position()` instead.
- `$gt$` and `$lt$` are unknown operators; use `&gt;` and `&lt;`.

Comment: not working this script    **<xsl:if test='../z:row[postion() &gt 5]'>**. Getting error like below     "' ' is an unexpected token. The expected token is ';'. Line 45, position 43."

Comment: Well, like the error messages says, it expects to see a semicolon (`;`) after the `&gt`:  `&gt;` is what I said to use; you cannot leave off the `;`.