# Layman's explanation for XPath using //, /, and local-name()?

Tags: xml, xpath

Just trying to understand what this XPath is doing

```
"//*[local-name()='Fault']/*[local-name()='detail']/*[local-name()='serviceFault']/*[local-name()='messages']/*[local-name()='message']/*[local-name()='code']"
```

What I believe it's doing is scanning the whole XML file to find Fault, detail, serviceFault, messages, message, code?

And if so is this an **and** function or an **or** function? And what I mean is, is looking for `fault` **or** `detail`, **or** ..., or is it doing looking `fault` **and** `detail` **and** `serviceFault` **and** ...?

Answer (score 1):

Understand:

1. `//e` selects all `e` elements in the XML document.
2. `p/c` selects the `c` children elements of a `p` parent element.
3. `*[local-name()='ln']` is the same as `ln` but ignores XML namespaces.

Then, your XPath *ignores XML namespaces and selects all `code` elements in the document that have a heritage of `Fault/detail/serviceFault/messages/message`, where `Fault` may occur anywhere in the XML document.*

**See also**

- [Difference between "//" and "/" in XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43100052/290085)
- [How does XPath deal with XML namespaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40796231/290085)