# Why is my XPath to select text not working?

Tags: python, xml, web-scraping, xpath, lxml

How do you access a text in an XPath if it doesn't have a node?
The text is in quotation marks and on seperate line inside another node

I'm having trouble choosing the correct element in an XPath

```
 <span>
    <a href="www.imagine_a_link_here.org">
      "
                This is the text I need to access
             "
    </a>
 </span>
```

I'd normally do this by writing

```
import requests
from lxml import html,etree
from lxml.html import document_fromstring

page = requests.get('https://www.the_link_im_trying_to_webscrape.org')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
the_text_i_need_to_access_xpath = '/span/a/text()'
the_text_i_need_to_access = tree.xpath(the_text_i_need_to_access_xpath)
```

Unfortunately this is only returning an empty list. Does anyone know how I have to modify the XPath in order to get the string I'm looking for?

Comment: For the sample HTML you posted, that XPath is correct and should select the text inside of the anchor. Are you sure that the HTML doesn't include other wrapping elements, such as `<html>` and `<body>`? You might try using a more generic XPath with the descendant axis: i.e. `//span/a/text()`

Comment: @MadsHansen: if you hard code the text, it will not give a result

Answer (score 2):

> How do you access a text in an XPath if it doesn't have a node?

Text in an XML or HTML document will be associated with a node.  That's not the problem here.  And the `" "` delimiters are just there to show you surrounding whitespace.

As presented your XPath should select the text within the `a` element.  Here're some reasons that may not be happening:

1. As @MadsHansen [mentioned in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66145117/how-do-you-access-a-text-in-an-xpath-if-it-doesnt-have-a-node-the-text-is-in-qu/66145272#comment116942386_66145117), the root element of your actual HTML may not be a `span` as shown.  See:

   - [Difference between "//" and "/" in XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43100052/290085)
2. The text may not be loaded at the time of your XPath execution because the document hasn't completely loaded or because JavaScript dynamically changes the DOM later.   See:

   - [Selenium wait until document is ready](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15122864/290085)
   - [Selenium WebDriver: Wait for complex page with JavaScript to load](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10720325/290085)
3. [`fromstring()`](https://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html#parsing-html) can use a bit more magic than might be expected:

> `fromstring(string)`:
> Returns `document_fromstring` or `fragment_fromstring`, based on
> whether the string looks like a full document, or just a fragment.

Given this, here is an update to your code that will select the targeted text as expected:

```
import requests
from lxml import html
from lxml.html import document_fromstring

htmlstr = """
<span>
   <a href="www.imagine_a_link_here.org">
     "
               This is the text I need to access
            "
   </a>
</span>
"""

tree = html.fromstring(htmlstr)
print(html.tostring(tree))
the_text_i_need_to_access_xpath = '//span/a/text()'
the_text_i_need_to_access = tree.xpath(the_text_i_need_to_access_xpath)
print(the_text_i_need_to_access)
```

Or, if you don't need/want the HTML surprises, this also selects the text:

```
import lxml.etree as ET

xmlstr = """
 <span>
    <a href="www.imagine_a_link_here.org">
      "
                This is the text I need to access
             "
    </a>
 </span>
"""

root = ET.fromstring(xmlstr)
print(root.xpath('/span/a/text()'))
```

**Credit:** Thanks to [@ThomasWeller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/480982/thomas-weller) for pointing out the additional complications and helping to resolve them.

Comment: If you hard code the text, it will not give a result, even if span is the root element. Neither / nor /span selects something.

Comment: @ThomasWeller: Hi Thomas, tell me what you mean by hard-coding the text -- I'm not following.   It seems like you're saying that if the XPath references the targeted text improperly, it won't match.   Agree there, but OP references it only as `text()`, so not sure I'm following your point.

Comment: Lol, yeah, that's a bit of mess.  It's going to be hard to reproduce without a server that returns OP's document.

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228547/lxml-htmlelement

Comment: No need to get a string from a server. Just hard-code it

Comment: thanks for the help kjhughes, i looked into your suggestions. Ive already iterated between "/" and "//" in every place i could think of and it didnt change the result. i also added a rudimentary timer so that the page definition but before the tree definition, but it also didnt help :/

Comment: @Alfred: Ah, I see now what's confusing matters.  See updated answer.

Comment: Thank you so much kjhughes and Thomas Weller! Looks very promising))  I will now sleep for 12 hrs and hopefully, when i wake up, ill be able to implement all of your suggestions! Cheers guys))