# XPath multiple, duplicate anonymous namespaces

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, xml-namespaces

I need to process the data in an XML file similar to this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <bpr:release xmlns:bpr="http://www.bp.co.uk/product/release">
        <bpr:contents>
            <process id="1" name="Process 1" xmlns="http://www.bp.co.uk/product/process">
                <process name="Process 1"></process>
            </process>
            <process id="2" name="Process 2" xmlns="http://www.bp.co.uk/product/process">
                <process name="Process 1"></process>
            </process>
            <object id="1" name="Object 1" xmlns="http://www.bp.co.uk/product/process">
                <process name="Object 1" ></process>
            </object>
            <work-queue id="1" name="Queue1" xmlns="http://www.bp.co.uk/product/work-queue"/>
            <process-group id="1" xmlns="http://www.bp.co.uk/product/process-group">
                <members>
                    <process id="1"/>
                    <process id="2"/>
                </members>
            </process-group>
            <object-group id="1" xmlns="http://www.bp.co.uk/product/object-group">
                <members>
                    <object id="1"/>
                    <object id="2"/>
                </members>
            </object-group>
        </bpr:contents>
    </bpr:release>
```

For example, I need to extract the `/bpr:release/bpr:contents/process/process` nodes for analysis, but I get nulls or this error:

```
System.Xml.XPath.XPathException
  HResult=0x80131943
  Message=Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed. This query has a prefix, variable, or user-defined function.
  Source=System.Xml
```

I see that the file has multiple anonymous namespaces, and there is the same namespace used twice.    I've tried various combinations, for example:

```
XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
xmldoc.LoadXml(xmlPath);
var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("bpr", "http://www.bp.co.uk/product/release");
nsmgr.AddNamespace("bpp", "http://www.bp.co.uk/product/process");
nsmgr.AddNamespace("bpo", "http://www.bp.co.uk/product/process");
nsmgr.AddNamespace("bpwq", "http://www.bp.co.uk/product/work-queue");
nsmgr.AddNamespace("bppg", "http://www.bp.co.uk/product/process-group");
nsmgr.AddNamespace("bpog", "http://www.bp.co.uk/product/object-group");
XmlNodeList p;
XmlNodeList r;
try { r = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/bpr:release"); } catch { }
try { r = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//bpr:release"); } catch { }
try { r = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("bpr:release"); } catch { }
try { r = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/release"); } catch { }
try { r = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//release"); } catch { }
try { r = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("release"); } catch { }
try { p = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("process"); } catch { }
try { p = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("bpp:process"); } catch { }
try { p = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/process"); } catch { }
try { p = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/bpp:process"); } catch { }
try { p = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//process"); } catch { }
try { p = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//bpp:process"); } catch { }
try { p = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/bpr:release/bpr:contents/process/process"); } catch { }
```

What is the correct XPath to get each of the child nodes of `bpr:release`, `bpr:contents`, `process/process`, `object/process`, etc.? How to use the `XMLNamespaceManager` for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're adding namespace prefix declarations to your `XmlNamespaceManager`, but you're not using `nsmgr` in your calls to `SelectNodes()`.

```
try { r = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/bpr:release", nsmgr); } catch { }
                                           ^^^^^^^
```

Fix up the other calls accordingly.

Note also that your first example XPath,

```
/bpr:release/bpr:contents/process/process
```

should be

```
/bpr:release/bpr:contents/bpp:process/bpp:process
```

given your declaration:

```
nsmgr.AddNamespace("bpp", "http://www.bp.co.uk/product/process");
```

Finally, you should remove duplicate prefix declarations (e.g. `bpp`/`bpo`) in some of the `AddNamespace()` calls.

### See also

- [How does XPath deal with XML namespaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40796231/290085)
- [Difference between "//" and "/" in XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43100052/290085)